# Leakage of java.exe processes

Tags: emacs, clojure, swank, swank-clojure

In Emacs + clojure-mode/swank-clojure, when I quit, the java.exe process that was created doesn't get actually killed (as much as I select 'y' when asked for it). What could be the cause?

Comment: How do you start clojure in your setup? Using clojure-jack-in or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

test with the latest version of lieningen `lein upgrade` and then open an issue on the [swank-clojure issue page](https://github.com/technomancy/swank-clojure/issues)